# Can't solve this equation: $A = K(1+ \Bbb i)^5 - (K-B)(1+ \Bbb i)^5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$A = K(1+ \Bbb i)^5 - (K-B)(1+ \Bbb i)^5$

The solution seems to be $A = B(1+ \Bbb i)^5$. I'm not very good at maths. Can someone please explain the steps to get there? I'm sure it's fairly simple, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$(K-B) (1 + \Bbb i)^5 = K (1 + \Bbb i)^5 - B (1 + \Bbb i)^5 ,$$ so that you equality looks like $$A = K(1 + \Bbb i)^5 - (K-B) (1 + \Bbb i)^5 = K(1 + \Bbb i)^5 - \left( K (1 + \Bbb i)^5 - B (1 + \Bbb i)^5 \right) = \\ K(1 + \Bbb i)^5 - K (1 + \Bbb i)^5 + B (1 + \Bbb i)^5 = B (1 + \Bbb i)^5 ,$$

because the first two terms on the last line cancel out.

Note, too, that this is not an equation (there is no unknown quantity here), but just an equality between two quantities.

Comment: What is an equation, if not an equality between two quantities?  I don't see that there must be an unknown; I'd call $2+3 = 5$ an equation, too.

Comment: @BrianTung: No, that is a *mathematical identity*; the same stands true for $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$, for instance (identity, not equation).

Comment: Thank you, I understand the steps to the solution! I'll keep your extra note in mind too. Thank you again.

Comment: Interesting.  Wikipedia agrees with you; Wolfram MathWorld agrees with me.  I'm fine with letting there be multiple interpretations; I wasn't aware that there were!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, treat the $(1+i)^5$ opaquely, as an atomic term $\xi$.  Then you have

$$
A = K\xi - (K-B)\xi
$$

So if you start out with $K$ whatsits, and you subtract out $K-B$ whatsits, then how many whatsits do you have left?

Comment: Very simple way to explain it, thank you, this really helped too!

Comment: You're welcome!  You seemed to waffle about which answer to accept.  Don't worry about that; if you want to accept Alex's answer, you should do that.  (You can always upvote the answers later, if/when you gain enough reputation.)